# Is there a Lightspeed 5.x NuGet package that can be used with ASP.Net 5?

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, lightspeed

I did a search on NuGet and couldn't find a Lightspeed NuGet package.

I have pro license for Lightspeed 5 so I have all the binaries I need to use Lightspeed in a non-ASP.Net 5 code.

However, it is my understanding that ASP.Net 5 doesn't allow you to allow you to reference DLLs directly, you have to create a NuGet package first.

So, I created a NuGet package of my POCO objects, DB context and Lightspeed references and added it to a .Net Framework 4.5 console application; it added the appropriate references (NuGet spec I used is show below).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$id$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <references>
      <reference file="$id$.dll" />
      <reference file="Mindscape.LightSpeed.dll" />
      <reference file="Mindscape.LightSpeed.Linq.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\Mindscape.Lightspeed\Mindscape.LightSpeed.dll" target="lib\net45\Mindscape.LightSpeed.dll" />
    <file src="..\Mindscape.Lightspeed\Mindscape.LightSpeed.Linq.dll" target="lib\net45\Mindscape.LightSpeed.Linq.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

However, this didn't work as expect when I tried to add this package to my to my ASP.Net 5 website (package added but using statement causes a compiler error).

Does anyone know a work-around to get Lightspeed working with ASP.Net 5?

Ideally Mindscape would publish a NuGet package.

Comment: asp.net 5 is in beta and still changing a lot, it won't be officially released until early 2016, it is not surprising that 3rd parties don't have their wares ready at this point. best bet is to contact the vendor to find out if/when they will have anything available.

Comment: Yeah, I put the posted the same question on the Mindscape form in the Lightspeed section.  They used to have NuGet packages for Lightspeed but I think they may have taken them away because it allowed people use the software for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the have their own NuGet feed that is listed in the "Keys" section of your subscription

Comment: Their NuGet feed doesn't seem to work ASP.Net 5 projects yet